# Is there a way to add a dynamic amount of points to a point counter?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

What I'm trying to do is find a way to add a dynamic amount of 'points' from a timer to a point counter, for example if you finished the level with 86 seconds left, how could I add 86 points to the counter? I am currently using logic bricks to accomplish the point counter and the timer, below are screenshots of how I've set up the logic bricks for both the timer and the point counter.

> Timer Logic
>   [image: timer code]
>
> Point Counter Logic
>   [image: counter code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the Property Actuator add the value from property counter to the value of property points:

[image]